# Is it possible to pass variables to actions using Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.

In my controller I have (can I have?!):

```
def action_name(variable_name)
  ...
end
```

How can I pass the value of the "variable_name" using this syntax

```
[...] :url => { :action => :action_name("name") } [...]
```

**? Is it possible?**

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that? Can you given an example? I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In view: `:url => {:action => :action_name, :variable_name => 'dog'}`

In controller:

```
def action_name
  variable_name = params[:variable_name]
  @something = Something.where(:name => variable_name)
  #More code in this method
end
```

This code will pass variable_name as a part of querystring in URL: `http://site.com/something?variable_name=dog`
Obviously, don't use this approach for sensitive data, and use :session[:variable_name] instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible. However, why don't you use the params hash instead to get that param?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `session` or `flash`. e.g.

```
def action1
  session[:your_key] = some_object
  redirect_to some_action_path
end

def action2
  @some_object = session[:your_key]
  # ...
end
```